# multiple file upload с предпросмотром

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, изображения, fileupload

В общем имеется следующий код https://jsfiddle.net/xyz78apr/

```
function readImagesURL(input) {
    if (input.files) {

        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++)
        {
            (function(file) {

                var reader = new FileReader();  
                reader.onload = function(e) {

                    var id = $('.image').length;

                    var image = '<div class="col-sm-2">';
                    image += '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" class="image_upload_preview img-thumbnail">';
                    image += '<input type="file" id="image-'+id+'" class="image" name="file['+id+']" value="'+e.target.result+'" accept="image/*">';
                    image += '<button type="button" class="change_img btn btn-block btn-primary">Изменить</button>';
                    image += '</div>';

                    $('.gallery .row').append(image);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            })(input.files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что при отправке на сервер получаю пустой массив. К примеру выбрал 3 изображения для загрузки, получаю

```
["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(3) {
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
      [2]=>
      string(0) ""
      [3]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
```

Если после выполнения readImagesURL вручную изменить изображение одиночное, то оно попадает на сервер, если же в цикле то пустой массив.

Идея сделать так, что выбираем неограниченное кол-во изображений для загрузки, получаем предпросмотр, при чем каждое изображение можно изменить перед загрузкой на сервер.

Comment: Приведите код отправки на сервер. И можно даже код, что на сервере обрабатывает

Comment: Да на сервере обычный `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: Окай, но скрипт загрузки на сервер можно-то глянуть?))

Comment: Там MVC фреймворк, просто отправляем форму на action, а в action `var_dump($_FILES);` и все пока что, дальше смысла двигаться нет, массив то пустой :(

Comment: Ну без кода отправки ничего сказать нельзя..... я конечно сегодня получил звание победителя в битве экстрасенсов. Но это все равно никуда не годится)